# Sony Xperia Z3 flickering between charging and discharging

Tags: charging, sony-xperia-z3

When I plug my phone in it often has problems charging.  Both the green led light and the charging icon will flicker on and off every half a second.

This seems to happen at different times during charging.  Sometimes when I first plug it in, but will also do it for seemingly random intervals whilst plugged in. It seems to be always doing this when I wake up (having plugged it in the night before).

I have tried an assortment of charging cables and methods (not limited to):

- Supplied charger and cable.
- Supplied charger from Sony Xperia Z3 tablet
- Official magnetic charging dock with charger supplied with phone
- From PC & Mac via micro USB port
- From PC & Mac via magnetic charging cable
- Magnetic charging cable with supplied charger

It seems to me that it is not the chargers or cable (as my tablet charges from these perfectly fine).
Nor is it the ports as this happens with both the microUSB port and the magnetic charger.

Phone works fine otherwise I still get 90%+ charge, but never get it fully charged because of this. Just concerned this is bad for the battery, plus the flickering LED is pretty annoying at night ;)

N.B while writing this it has gone from flickering to, charging fine, to flickering again without me touching it.

Comment: I know it is not helpful, but I have the same phone and the same problem. I generally use the magnetic dock, so I cant make a good comparison with the charger cable. I just take it out and place it back, seems to do the trick sometimes (it did 5mins ago, after which I ended up here). - Any update from you on this?

Comment: Ditto on Samsung A3 running Android 6.0.1.